# VBA code will not update table field from form input

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to build a form to update fields in a table based on customer input in a form. The form has a criteria field, which is used to search for matching entries then an update field to update another Table field. My problem is that I cannot get the update to work when I reference the fields from the form. Here is the code:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim uiTAGNAME As String
Dim uoX_NAM As String

Forms![Prefill Xmtr Data]!TxtCPointTagname.SetFocus
uiTAGNAME = Forms![Prefill Xmtr Data]!TxtCPointTagname.Text

Forms![Prefill Xmtr Data]!TxtQTransmitter.SetFocus
uoX_NAM = Forms![Prefill Xmtr Data]!TxtQTransmitter.Text

Debug.Print uiTAGNAME
Debug.Print uoX_NAM

'no error, but no update
db.Execute "UPDATE [IO Data] SET [io data].x_nam = '  uoX_NAM ' " & _
    "WHERE [IO Data].tagname Like 'bkr7*';"
```

When I set a break, I can view the value of `uoX_NAM`, and it is updated from the form correctly.

I'm pretty sure I have the form field referenced incorrectly, but I have tried various other methods, none of which update the table.

If I try the following code, the correct fields update, but it is not the entry from the form:

```
'this updates the correct fields
db.Execute "UPDATE [IO Data] SET [io data].x_nam = 'BRKRCMD'" & _
    "WHERE [IO Data].tagname Like 'bkr7*';"
```

So my problem appears to be in how I reference the `uoX_NAM` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you execute SQL that you have dynamically constructed in code, do yourself this favor: store it in a string and Debug.Print the string before running it. I see that you've got `strSQL` declared, but you don't use it!

```
'current code:
strSQL = "UPDATE [IO Data] SET [io data].x_nam = '  uoX_NAM ' " & _
    "WHERE [IO Data].tagname Like 'bkr7*';"
Debug.Print strSQL
db.Execute strSQL
```

will print and run:

```
UPDATE [IO Data] SET [io data].x_nam = '  uoX_NAM ' WHERE [IO Data].tagname Like 'bkr7*';
```

Your current code changes sets the field to the literal text `uoX_NAM` exactly like your second code block sets the field to the literal text `BRKRCMD`. To insert the value of the variable, rather than its name, the variable name must be outside of any quotation marks and connected by `&`s like this:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [IO Data] SET [io data].x_nam = '" & uoX_NAM & "'" & _
    "WHERE [IO Data].tagname Like 'bkr7*';"
Debug.Print strSQL
db.Execute strSQL
```

will print and run:

```
UPDATE [IO Data] SET [io data].x_nam = 'YOUR VALUE HERE' WHERE [IO Data].tagname Like 'bkr7*';
```

Also, you can set your variables more directly and without `SetFocus` by referring to the Value of the control, rather than the Text property. Since Value is the default property, you can even omit `.Value` and refer to just the control name:

```
uiTAGNAME = Forms![Prefill Xmtr Data]!TxtCPointTagname
uoX_NAM = Forms![Prefill Xmtr Data]!TxtQTransmitter
```

Comment: There must be something else I am doing wrong. I had already tried several variations on your suggestion, but the table is still not updated - I had high hopes for the last line, I had not tried that.

Comment: Also, I still get errors if I attempt to set the variables directly as you suggested."You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus."    The form fields are unbound.    I know I left it out before, but the code is initiated from a button press.

Comment: Now that you have the SQL printed into the debug window, copy it onto the clipboard. Create a new query, switch it to SQL view, and paste the SQL into the window. If you then run the update query, you may get a more specific error message. If there's no error message this way but there's also no results, change the SQL into a SELECT query (without the UPDATE part) and confirm the number of rows that match the where criteria. No rows selected by where means no change in the target table and no error message..

Comment: that was a great suggestion. I get a "didn't update due to key violations" error. This code is almost identical to code which does update the fields[code]   db.Execute "UPDATE [IO Data] SET [io data].x_nam = 'BRKRCMD'" & _
    "WHERE [IO Data].tagname Like 'bkr7*';"[/code]

Comment: That suggests that there is an index on table [IO Data] that does not allow duplicates in some field or combination of fields. You already have records in your table that match the key combination-- you can't change the records you have selected to because they would become the second versions of whatever key you have.

Comment: Okay, I have figured out how to make this work.This field is only allowing certain values to be input via query. They are correct values (names) for the field, so this is not all bad, I just did not expect it. There is no Primary key to worry about, but I get a "key violation" whenever a query tries to update the field to an incorrect value. Thank you all for your help, especially @pteranodon, who gave me the clue to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for the help, Pteranodon's suggestion led me to the answer. The database I am working in is making changes in a linked database. anyway, there was a relationship with another table that I did not expect. That was causing the key violation.